# how can I make my left social sidebar adjacent with the post body?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I want to keep my left sidebar beside my post body in the left side without any space. I want to make it like this site link: http://digital-photography-school.com/10-signs-might-photo-geek .

I have tried for a long time but don't get any way. It is working fine in my screens and many of the screens but making problem in the big screens ( screen size like 24"). So if anyone can please help me that will be great for me.

I am using this plugin of wordpress : https://www.po.st/get-it . Here is my site link where you can check the problem: http://site4preview.site90.net/wordpress/title-for-post-1-will-go-here-2/ . Thanks.

I have given the code which I have used as extra with the plugin:

```
.pw-float-left{
  background:#ffffff;
  padding:10px;
  top:195px !important;
  left:0 !important;
  z-index:99;
  margin-top:0 !important;
 }    

 @media only screen and (min-width:1300px){ // Making problem in larger screens than this */
 .pw-float-left{
  left:7% !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have tried to set left position but when I increased the left side pixels then in the small screen it get on the post body. Also I have used plugin so there is nothing more code I have used.

Comment: Post your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ and then people can take a look at what you've attempted.

Comment: please read this `meta` before asking question in such a manner....http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: place it within your page container and give it a negative left value

Comment: I have read your link but how can I describe this problem if I don't give the site links ! that's why I put it and thanks for sharing this, I will remember this from the next time. @Mayank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like user574632 said:

> place it within your page container and give it a negative left value

If you can only change the CSS, add this:

```
.pw-float-left{
     background: none;
     margin-left: 50%;
     padding: none;
     top:195px !important;
     z-index:99;
     margin-top:0 !important;
 } 

.pw-widget {
     width: 60px;
     margin-left: -600px; //change this to move left/right
     background-color: #FFF;
     padding: 12px;
}
```

remove the min-width 1300px media query

Comment: I also thought something like this. Anyway It's working fine. Thanks.